# find the customer who with orders before 1/jan/2002 how can I write a this query in SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, date

find the customer who with orders **before** 1/jan/2002    how can I write a this query in SQL?

table
**Customer**- cno,fname,lname ,address
**oder**-oder_no,cno,oderdate
**oderline**-oder_no,product,Qty,cost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select * from Customer c Inner Join Order o On c.cno=o.cno 
 Where o.orderdate>'2002-01-01'
```

Orderdate is supposed to be of type datetime

Comment: Select * from Customer c Where c.cno=o.cno and o.orderdate>'2002-01-01'<<< is this wrong?

Comment: where is o in your above query. You need to build relation with order na?

Comment: Select * from Customer c ,oder as o Where c.cno=o.cno and o.orderdate>'2002-01-01'<<< is this wrong? sorry ....now?

Comment: select * from Customer as c ,oder as o,oderline as ol where c.cno=o.cno and o.oder_no=ol.oder_no and o.oderdate >= getdate() -1<<< is this query right for this question.>>> find the customer who placed oder today or yesterday?

Comment: why are u using orderline?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
select fname
from Customer c
where exists (select 1 from Order o where c.cno = o.cno and o.orderdate < '2002/01/01')
```

Comment: thanx but i need natural join query